# Why does table salt (NaCl) dissolve branded food?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

To dissolve branded food from e. g. a baking tray, there is the advice to pour table salt on it and heat it up in a baking oven or on a hotplate until the salt turns brown. From practice I confirm that it works.
But I'd like to know why it works. Can somebody please explain it in layman's terms (my chemistry knowledge is at a-grade)? What reaction(s) happen(s) here?

Comment: As far as I understand it, the salt (due to its large surface) takes up whatever becomes liquid in the pan, removing it from the hot surface. That way the iron becomes hotter faster. Thermally destroying old oil (or evaporating it) needs a lot of energy and takes time. Im interested to hear about other explanations!

Comment: Monovalent ions generally tend to dissolve things because they "sneak" into structures. I am curiou about a more scientific reasoning.

Comment: @GyroGearloose Hm, it sounds not unreasonable that single ions can diffuse into a polar solid, but I would expect that this *hardens* the structure instead of softening it.